# Loading Image as background

Tags: image

I am using blender 2.79b. I cannot see the image output even after i load an image. I used the properties panel to load the image. Under the 'Background Images' tab. I added an image file(i tried both ".png" & ".jpg" formats). Please guide me.

Comment: Try pressing numpad  5 to toggle orthographic view and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Background images only show up in cameras and the orthographic views. To get to the orthographic view, press numpad 1, 3 or 7 and then numpad 5, or press numpad 0 to go into the camera view